# iPhone redpark crash after aprox 20 readings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arduino

I have the following code and I wonder why after aprox. 20 measuments from the arduino my app crashes. It has something to do with the NSmutableArray. I my .h I have

NSMutableArray *values;

And the .m looks like this:

```
- (void) readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)length
{

    myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    int bytesRead = [rscMgr read:rxBuffer Length:length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) 
    {
    [myString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",((char *)rxBuffer)[i]]];
    }
    NSArray *arrayValues = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    textView.text = [arrayValues objectAtIndex:1];

}
```

Comment: What is the error message? - The `NSMutableArray *values;` is nowhere used in your code. What makes you think that the error has something to do with it?

Comment: There is no error message, the app just crashes. The problem is that I cannot log the things because of the redpark cable is connected. But as you se it there are no problems with the way I am instantiating the array?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain it. readBytesAvailable method has a loop for where in each iteration, just a single character is generated from data buffer.
Then if you are trying to divide into numbers the complete line that Arduino sends to iPhone causes that app crashes.
For example Arduino sends the next string of 3 numbers: "25 13 16"
iPhone app when readBytesAvailable starts, executes several iterations until buffer is empty doing operations inside loop:
    it.1=2
    it.2=5
    it.3= 
    it.4=1
    it.5=.3
    it.6= 
    it.7=1
    it.8=6
    it.9=

Answer (score 0):

(This is not really an answer, but it is too long for a comment).

- Even if you cannot debug the program in Xcode because the cable is already connected, you can connect the iPhone to Xcode later and see the Console output and Device Logs in the Organizer window.
- Are you sure that `rxBuffer` is large enough for the data?
- I would add `NSLog()` statements at various points to narrow down the problem. In particular the value of `length` and `bytesRead` would be interesting.

Comment: Thank for that reply, that was actually helpful!

Comment: @moryde: OK, fine. Did you solve your problem or do you want to provide more information so that we can help you?